# Can I use the "Vscode remote SSH" extension without a password?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access, remote-server

Can I use the "Vscode remote SSH" extension without a password?
I have a Linux server, my public key in the server and I know the username and the IP address.
also, I'm able to ssh to the server using the terminal.

** Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put something similar to your "C:\Users\yourhome\.ssh\config" that is known by vscode. I think "PreferredAuthentications" line is most important one.

```
Host vscode
    HostName 192.168.0.1
    User linuxusername
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile "C:\Users\yourhome\.ssh\privatekey"
```

Comment: Whenever the "PreferredAuthentications" line exists, I am getting an error message "Could not establish connection to hostname: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe." ?

Comment: Resolved! I was trying to point IdentityFile to a PuTTy (.ppk) file instead of OpenSSH format (no extension). I wish the error messages were more helpful though :/

Comment: This is how I got locked out of my server :(. Now I just get the error: "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive)."

Comment: If you get locked out, be sure that you added the public key with `ssh-copy-id {user}@{host}` BEFORE setting `PreferredAuthentications publickey`. If you didn't, just delete the line in the config file temporarily then readd it once you copy the public key over.

Comment: I still got the error, Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssap i-with-mic,password), The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe, after do ssh-copy-id {user}@{host}, The key was successfully added. then add PreferredAuthentications publickey to the .ssh/config file